# Proper use of mutexes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, mutex

I am starting with multi-threads in python (or at least it is possible that my script creates multiple threads). would this algorithm be the right usage of a Mutex? I haven't tested this code yet and it probably won't even work. I just want processData to run in a thread (one at time) and the main while loop to keep running, even if there is a thread in queue.

```
from threading import Thread
from win32event import CreateMutex
mutex = CreateMutex(None, False, "My Crazy Mutex")
while(1)
    t = Thread(target=self.processData, args=(some_data,))
    t.start()
    mutex.lock()

def processData(self, data)
    while(1)
        if mutex.test() == False:
            do some stuff
            break
```

Edit: re-reading my code I can see that it is grossly wrong. but hey, that's why I am here asking for help.

Comment: It is very difficult to figure out what you are trying to do. You'll need to explain your intent in more detail.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, sorry you are probably right. I want my code in processData to start in a new tread. I only want one thread to be able to process data at a time and in order of which data was sent to process data. I also want the main while loop to keep looping while other threads are in queue.

Comment: @Richard: Why do you want to use threads if you plan to serialise all processing anyway? What's wrong with a simple loop? Also, why do you want the main thread to keep looping? It will just burn CPU, possibly starving other threads.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos,
This is not my actual program. My actual script has reached over 500 lines of code, which include database entries and email. I want the main thread to just read a serial port so that there is less of a chance of the buffer being filled before the data received is processed. Correct me if I am wrong but I think this is exactly where one would use either threads or multiprocessing

Comment: @Richard: That makes sense for the main thread, but if all other processing is going to be sequential, then you could just create one other thread to do all that other work.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: that is kind of what I have done but a new thread is created each time a newline is found in the serial buffer instead of having just two threads. To be honest, I am not sure how to pass data to a thread that is already created.

Comment: Use Python's out-of-the-box [message queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html). You can dump the mutex in the process.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

I don't know why you're using the Window's Mutex instead of Python's.  Using the Python methods, this is pretty simple:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

mutex = Lock()

def processData(data):
    with mutex:
        print('Do some stuff')

while True:
    t = Thread(target = processData, args = (some_data,))
    t.start()
```

But note, because of the architecture of CPython (namely the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock)) you'll effectively only have one thread running at a time anyway--this is fine if a number of them are I/O bound, although you'll want to release the lock as much as possible so the I/O bound thread doesn't block other threads from running.

An alternative, for Python 2.6 and later, is to use Python's `multiprocessing` package.  It mirrors the `threading` package, but will create entirely new processes which *can* run simultaneously.  It's trivial to update your example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

mutex = Lock()

def processData(data):
    with mutex:
        print('Do some stuff')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        p = Process(target = processData, args = (some_data,))
        p.start()
```

Comment: "this is fine if a number of them are I/O bound" Actually it's also fine if they're CPU bound, so long as this is in calls to libraries written in C rather than in pure Python code (e.g. if you're manipulating large matrices in numpy) because the GIL is unlocked during those calls.

Comment: @demented hedgehog: the `mutex` module is deprecated. Creating mutexes using the `threading` and `multiprocessing` modules, which is done in the answer, is not deprecated.

Comment: excelent for I/O specially alignment of messages

Answer (score 21):

I would like to improve [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311157/929902) from [chris-b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9161/chris-b)
a little bit more.

See below for my code:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import threading
mutex = Lock()


def processData(data, thread_safe):
    if thread_safe:
        mutex.acquire()
    try:
        thread_id = threading.get_ident()
        print('\nProcessing data:', data, "ThreadId:", thread_id)
    finally:
        if thread_safe:
            mutex.release()


counter = 0
max_run = 100
thread_safe = False
while True:
    some_data = counter        
    t = Thread(target=processData, args=(some_data, thread_safe))
    t.start()
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter >= max_run:
        break
```

In your first run if you set `thread_safe = False` in while loop, mutex will not be used, and threads will step over each others in print method as below;

[image: Not Thread safe]

but, if you set `thread_safe = True` and run it, you will see all the output comes perfectly fine;

[image: Thread safe]

hope this helps.

Comment: copy `thread_safe` at the start of `processData()` and use that copy within the function.  `thread_safe` is an external state variable which could change during the execution, again leading to no releasing the mutex.

Answer (score 16):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from threading import Lock

def myfunc(i, mutex):
    mutex.acquire(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Thread: %d" %i
    mutex.release()


mutex = Lock()
for i in range(0,10):
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(i,mutex))
    t.start()
    print "main loop %d" %i
```

Output:

```
main loop 0
main loop 1
main loop 2
main loop 3
main loop 4
main loop 5
main loop 6
main loop 7
main loop 8
main loop 9
Thread: 0
Thread: 1
Thread: 2
Thread: 3
Thread: 4
Thread: 5
Thread: 6
Thread: 7
Thread: 8
Thread: 9
```

Comment: There's a potential deadlock.  If the print statement throws an Exception, you'll never release the mutex.  You need to use `try/release` or `with` to ensure the lock is released.  See my answer.

Comment: Also, there's no need to pass the mutex as an argument to the function.  It's available in the global scope.

Answer (score 11):

You have to unlock your Mutex at sometime...