# "lock" resource when user opens and unlocks when he finishes

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask version 0.10.1 and python version 2.7.6

I have a web application that manages some orders.
Let's say we have 3 orders:

```
order 1
order 2
order 3
```

There is a view

```
@main.route(/prder/<int:orderid>, methods=['GET'])
edit(orderid):
   pass
```

The view is accesible only to registered users and I have a user object.
Let's say we have to users user A and user B.

When A edits order 1 this order should not be editable by user B.

I need a mechanism that "locks" the order and the order is inaccessible for edits when user A is working on the order.

This "lock" need to be revoked when the user finishes editing*

- There is the scenario that user A closed the browser or stopped working on the order. Then I do not want the order to be "locked" forever.

Any ideas what is the best way to achieve the above functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used flask, but it sounds like you want a [mutex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html#module-mutex) (example for multi-threading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310049/proper-use-of-mutexes-in-python)).  What the behaviour should be when B tries to edit something A is already editing is another matter.

As for not being locked forever, a little more information is required.  By "stopped working on the order," do you mean was idle for some time, or closed some window?  I'm pretty sure the `try...finally` construction would unlock the mutex in the event that whatever was inside of the `try` block was prematurely terminated, but I'm don't have enough experience with it to tell you for certain.

Comment: stopped working on the order could be many things. Could be idle for some time ( forgetting closing the browser/lose internet connection etc), Also when he closes the browser window or if he clicks a save button on the order.