# Python threading/multiprocessing don't need Mutex?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

For a supervisor-like project, I use the threading library to manage
some child process. At some point, the user can prompt command to send
instructions to the process management thread. These commands are stored in
a Queue object shared between the main process and process management thread.
I thought I'll need mutex to solve concurrency issues so I made a a little
script to try it out, but without mutex first to be sure I get the expected
concurrency issue.

I expected from the script to print a messy list of int every second:

```
import threading
import time

def longer(l, mutex=None):
    while 1:
        last_val = l[-1]
        l.append(last_val + 1)
        time.sleep(1)
    return

dalist = [0]
t = threading.Thread(target=longer, args=(dalist,))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while 1:
    last_val = dalist[-1]
    dalist.append(last_val + 1)
    print dalist
    time.sleep(1)
```

But in fact it print a nice list of following int like these:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311157/4057461) answer in another post I thought it come from the threading library, so I did the same with the multiprocessing lib:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def longer(l, mutex=None):
    while 1:
        last_val = l[-1]
        l.append(last_val + 1)
        time.sleep(1)
    return

dalist = [0]
t = mp.Process(target=longer, args=(dalist,))
t.start()

while 1:
    last_val = dalist[-1]
    dalist.append(last_val + 1)
    print dalist
    time.sleep(1)
```

But I got the same result, a bit 'slower' :

```
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So I wonder do I really need mutex to manage a Queue-like object
shared between thread ???
And also, from one of the code above, how could I effectively reproduce
the expected concurrency issue I search for ?

Thanks for reading

**Edit 1:**
From the remarks of [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33435680/4057461) I change the first snippet and I manage to have some sort of race condition by moving the sleep call inside the 'longer' function between value retrieval and list appending:

```
import threading
import time

def longer(l, mutex=None):
    while 1:
        last_val = l[-1]
        time.sleep(1)
        l.append(last_val + 1)
    return 

dalist = [0]
t = threading.Thread(target=longer, args=(dalist,))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while 1:
    last_val = dalist[-1]
    dalist.append(last_val + 1)
    print dalist
    time.sleep(1)
```

which give me stuffs like that:

```
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

and I manage to solve my artificial issue using threading Lock like that:

```
import threading
import time

def longer(l, mutex=None):
    while 1:
        if mutex is not None:
            mutex.acquire()
        last_val = l[-1]
        time.sleep(1)
        l.append(last_val + 1)
        if mutex is not None:
            mutex.release()
    return

dalist = [0]
mutex = threading.Lock()
t = threading.Thread(target=longer, args=(dalist, mutex))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while 1:
    if mutex is not None:
        mutex.acquire()
    last_val = dalist[-1]
    dalist.append(last_val + 1)
    if mutex is not None:
        mutex.release()
    print dalist
    time.sleep(1)
```

which then produce:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Note that the idiomatic way to acquire and release a mutex would be using a `with` statement rather than explicit calls to `acquire` and `release` methods. Also, one rarely needs to pass the mutex to the function - a mutex protecting a global resource will reside in a global variable, and a mutex protecting an object-level resource will reside in the object and be reachable as `self.some_attribute`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info :) I come from C programming and I learned that global variables are bad habits (security issue, code cleaness etc..), do you know if global variable is a special concern in Python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code snippet contains a race condition and does need a mutex. The global interpreter lock makes the race condition rare because one thread is running at any given time. However, every several bytecode instructions the current thread relinquishes the ownership of the global interpreter lock to give other threads a chance to run. So, given your code:

```
last_val = dalist[-1]
dalist.append(last_val + 1)
```

If the bytecode switch happens after executing the first line, another thread will pick up the same `last_val` and append it to the list. After giving control back to the initial thread, the value stored in `last_val` will be appended to the list, for the second time. A mutex would prevent the race in the obvious way: a context switch between list access and append would give control to the other thread, but it would immediately get blocked in the mutex and relinquish control back to the original thread.

Your second example only "works" because the two processes have separate list instances. Modifying one list doesn't affect the other, so the other process might as well not be running. Although `multiprocessing` has a drop-in replacement API for `threading`, the underlying concepts are vastly different, which needs to be accounted for when switching from one to the other.

Comment: Ok so with the first snippet the race condition issue may be more obvious if I used more than one thread I guess ?

Comment: @shorty_ponton Yes, and smaller sleep times, etc. And, of course, inserting even a tiny sleep before `dalist.append(...)` should provoke it.