# I am testing out threading.Time in this little game I made, but it keeps overlapping

Tags: python

```
import time
from threading import Timer
from random import randint
print("Every wrong answer is a 3s delay; you have 30s")
end = False
def lose():
    print(end)
    print("Time up!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Score is",pts,", with",wrong,"wrong answers.")
    time.sleep(1)
    input("enter to quit")
    quit()
timer = Timer(10,lose)
timer.start()
pts = 0
wrong = 0
while end == False:
    a = randint(5,50)
    b = randint(5,50)
    print(a,"+",b)
    ans = input()
    if ans.isnumeric():
        ans = int(ans)
    if ans == a+b:
        print("correct")
        pts = pts+1
    else:
        print("wrong,",a+b)
        wrong = wrong+1
        print("delay")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("delay end")
    print("")
```

When the timer finishes, the loop overlaps the 'lose' function, and it messes up on the line like this:

```
Time up!

45 + 10
55
Score iscorrect 
3 
, with29  0+  wrong answers.37


enter to quitwrong,p
 66
delay
```

How do I fix this issue?
Sorry if this question has already been answered, but I want to know.

Comment: looks like the GIL isn't working properly on that one. Surprising.

Comment: Don't you remember — threads are run sumultaneously, and with varying speed, and all this timing is unpredictable (depends on many factors). Can you avoid using threads? Can you go for asynchronous functions perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, I think I could do that instead, so the while loop will repeat until start time is 30 less than current time, then 'lose' will play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should probably avoid using threads altogether, as mentioned in the comments.

However, if you are going to use threads, consider using a [mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311157/2744663) to ensure that multiple threads are not trying to write to stdout at the same time.

For example:

```
# setup at the beginning:
from threading import Thread, Lock
mutex = Lock()

# surrounding each print statement:
mutex.acquire()
try:
    print('text')
finally:
    mutex.release()
```

Comment: I'd probably use [`with mutex:`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement), but yeah.