# How to use Queue with threading properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am new to  queue & threads kindly help with the below code , here I am trying to execute the function **hd** , I need to run the function multiple times but only after a single run has been completed

```
import queue
import threading
import time

fifo_queue = queue.Queue()

def hd():
    print("hi")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("done")


for i in range(3):
    cc = threading.Thread(target=hd)
    fifo_queue.put(cc)
    cc.start()
```

**Current Output**

```
hi
hi
hi
donedonedone
```

**Expected Output**

```
hi
done   
hi
done
hi
done​
```

Comment: *"I need to run the function multiple times but only after a single run has been completed"* doesn't this defeat the purpose of parallel processing? Looks like you might want a simple loop?

Comment: You would need [mutex lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524/what-is-a-mutex)
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311157/5319180) out for an example usage.

Comment: thanks mozway yeah i am aware regular for loop wil work on this scenario just wandering how i can use with Queue  so later if required i can use it with complex functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) for your purposes

> A semaphore manages an internal counter which is decremented by each acquire() call and incremented by each release() call. The counter can never go below zero; when acquire() finds that it is zero, it blocks, waiting until some other thread calls release().

A default value of Semaphore is `1`,

> class threading.Semaphore(value=1)

so only one thread would be active at once:

```
import queue
import threading
import time

fifo_queue = queue.Queue()

semaphore = threading.Semaphore()


def hd():
    with semaphore:
        print("hi")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("done")


for i in range(3):
    cc = threading.Thread(target=hd)
    fifo_queue.put(cc)
    cc.start()
```

```
hi
done
hi
done
hi
done
```

---

As [@user2357112supportsMonica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) mentioned in comments [RLock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#rlock-objects) would be more safe option

> class threading.RLock

> This class implements reentrant lock objects. A reentrant lock **must be released by the thread that acquired it**. Once a thread has acquired a reentrant lock, the same thread may acquire it again without blocking; the thread must release it once for each time it has acquired it.

```
import queue
import threading
import time

fifo_queue = queue.Queue()

lock = threading.RLock()


def hd():
    with lock:
        print("hi")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("done")


for i in range(3):
    cc = threading.Thread(target=hd)
    fifo_queue.put(cc)
    cc.start()
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the default value of the semaphore is 1 ;)

Comment: @mozway good point, thx. Added to answer

Comment: If you're just going to use a semaphore like this, a lock would be more appropriate, either `threading.Lock` or `threading.RLock`. (`RLock` is usually the safest default, avoiding several classes of bugs that can happen with `Lock` or `Semaphore`.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, `RLock` seems better for this task. Could you tell about bugs that can happen with `Semaphore`?

Comment: @Eugenij: If a thread tries to release an `RLock` a different thread is holding, you get a `RuntimeError`, letting you know about the problem. If you try that with a `Lock` or `Semaphore`, the release silently succeeds, hiding bugs.

Comment: Plus, if a thread tries to acquire a lock it's already holding, with a `Lock` or 1-count `Semaphore`, it silently deadlocks. With an `RLock`, the second acquire succeeds, and the lock is only unlocked once the thread unlocks it twice. This is important for cases where you have functions that do `with lock: ...` delegating to other functions that also need to do `with lock: ...`.

Comment: @Eugenij but how you release the thread from the queue after it's done? Should you put in the end of `hd()` function `fifo_queue.get()` command? will it be danger a bit?

Answer (score 0):

please put the print("down") before sleep.
it will work fine.
Reason:
your program will do this:
thread1
:
print 
sleep 
print
but while the thread is sleeping, other threads will be working and printing their first command.
in my way the thread will write the first, write the second and then go to sleep and wait for other threads to show up.