# Call parent function from multiple child processes

Tags: python

I'm trying to save on database speed, and the parent currently listens for updates in a function and writes it into a file, while the child processes constantly read the data and if it's updated they do certain actions

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_info(self):
        with open(FILENAME, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
            if text == '':
                # writer is currently writing, retry
                return self.get_codes_from_file()
            data = json.loads(text)

        return data

    
    def main(self):
        while True:
            data = self.get_info()
            if data_changed:
                ...

    def writer(self):
        while True:
            data = mongo_client.find(...)
                
            with open(FILENAME, 'w') as f:
                f.write(json.dumps(data)) #Writer updated file.

            time.sleep(0.02)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    AMOUNT_OF_THREADS = 16
    threads = []
    threads.append(Process(target=start_writer))
    for i in range(AMOUNT_OF_THREADS):
        threads.append(Process(target=start_booker))

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

This brings the problem that a lot of processes are always reading the file, and for some reason I see it takes some processes 100-1000ms to react to information getting updated, which is not OK for my purposes. I want for the child processes to call one main function that will return them the most recent information, however by looking on StackOverflow I didn't quite see how that could be accomplished. So, ideally, I want something like this:

```
def call_parent_function_to_get_data():
    return mongo_client.find(...)

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_info(self):
        call_parent_function_to_get_data()

    def main(self):
        while True:
            data = self.get_info()
            if data_changed:
                ...
```

However in this scenario of course every child gets the data on their own and the database gets overwhelmed.

Thank you for any help

Comment: [Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70492568/how-to-use-queue-with-threading-properly) might help here.

Comment: If you have multiple threads all "polling" for changes to one single file, you'll end up in all sorts of pain. Either use a single thread or you're going to have to implement some form of locking

Comment: use a Message Queue system like RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ

Comment: thank you guys. rabbitMQ seems like the best option for me